# make unordered image list spacing smaller

Tags: css

I am trying to make the spacing between the images less. I have tried grid gap, but its not seeming to make any difference. I just want to be able to control this area.

```css
#Listed {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(1px, 1fr));
}

.Img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Listed">
  <div class="style">
    <img class="Img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1">
  </div>
  <div class="style">
    <img class="Img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/2"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="style">
    <img class="Img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/3"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="style">
    <img class="Img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/4"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="style">
    <img class="Img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/34"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="style">
    <img class="Img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/6"><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by using `auto-fill` which will cause the elements to fill the entire width. Try using `auto-fit` with a 60px value in the `minmax` like...

```css
#Listed {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(60px, 1fr));
}

.Img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Listed">
  <div class="style">
    <img class="Img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1">
  </div>
  <div class="style">
    <img class="Img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/2"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="style">
    <img class="Img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/3"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="style">
    <img class="Img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/4"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="style">
    <img class="Img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/34"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="style">
    <img class="Img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/6"><br>
  </div>
</div>
```